# Suddenly, my server is down without any conf or something

Tags: apache, apache2, vps

I did not do anything on my server (**vps** account on linode.com) such as configuration or something. But, suddenly my server is down. When i try to start **apache**, i saw this error message:
(
Starting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 
no listening sockets available, shutting down 
Unable to open **logs** 
failed!
)

I did try to start apache with some way and i face now "Starting web server: **apache2** failed!"

Thanks for your help,
Erman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably means another server (probably apache itself) is running on same port. If you have shell access to server, try to determine which process is using port 80. (netstat --listen perhaps, do some google) and then kill the process by kill command.

Comment: nginx trying to use port 80 also. But, unless i stop it, i can't start apache2. (facing error: Starting web server: apache2)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried linode.com support? This is probably your best bet.

You could also try restarting all of your services (not just Apache, but everything that is available to you to restart).